# Making a program that counts the amount of occurrences for each letter in the alphabet issues

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
string text;
int i;
char x;
int n = 0;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Enter some text: " << endl;
    getline(cin, text);
    for (x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<= text.length(); i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == x)
            {
                n++;
                cout << x << ": " << n << endl;

            }
        }

    }

}
```

So I want it to print out the occurrence for each letter that appears in the string but instead, I am getting this:

**Input**: hello

**Output:**

```
e: 1
h: 2
l: 3
l: 4
o: 5
```

I understand why it is counting up each time it finds a letter, but how do I get it to display the number of times each one of those letters actually come up. For example this is what I want it to say:

```
e: 1
h: 1
l: 2
o: 1
```

Comment: Sounds like homework!

Comment: Surprisingly, it's actually not. I got this off of my old teachers website and its for a more advanced class and I thought it would be fun to try. @HappyCoder

Comment: Well I can give you pointers then. To begin with, think whether you really need two loops.

Answer (score 0):

In the start of each loop(x) you should reset n to 0.

Also you should move the statment

```
cout << x << ": " << n << endl;
```

From the second loop the end of the first loop